# Deleted files don't appear in trash bin of mounted / external drives

Tags: mount, trash

I am using Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS. Apart from my home folder, I am using two extra physical hard-drives (/mnt/WORK and /mnt/SAVE).
Now, whenever I delete files on these drives by hitting "del", I get the notification, that the files will be deleted permanently. Indeed, they don't go into the trash bin on these drives - but are obviously deleted immediately.
When I delete files from my home folder, the do go to the trash bin.
I would like to have the trash bin functionality on the mounted drives as well - can anyone tell me how to enable it?
Thx in advance for your help.

Comment: Provide information on what the file systems are and how the drives are mounted. It is likely a permission issue, where the system cannot create and write to the user trash.